Find Jordan Form to T linear Transformation based on matrix A
I'm working through this question and would appreciate some help:
A matrix: \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}
Define T linear map $T: M_4(C)  \rightarrow  M_4(C)$, $T(X)=AX$ 
Find jordan Form of T
I already found that the Eigenvalues ​​must be 1 and -1 
A is symmetric, so T is symmetric, so T unitary diagonal
it says The minimal polynomail is $(x-1)(x+1)$ 
But Can't think of a way to find the only Jordan Form, is that even possible?
i was thinking about
If X eigenvector of T for Eigenvalue 1
So
$T(X)=X$,
$AX=X$
But stuck here

$T$ is diagonalizable because its minimal polynomial has simple roots. Note that $A^2=Id$ implies $T^2 = Id$

i need to know the exact Diagonal Form, meaning i need to know the Geometric Multiplicities of 1 and -1
this is where i stuck @Gribouillis

If $T(X) = X$, what can you say about the columns of $X$ ?

its columns are Eigenvector ​​of A, right?
I calculated it and found out that the column space of X is of dimension 2
But how does it help me?

With 1 eigenvector of $A$ you can make 4 independent eigenvectors of $T$.

Oh nice, so after also calculating the -1 eigenvalue of A,
It is possible to create another 8 independent eigenvectors of T
So basically the only Jordan form is Diag(1X8,-1X8)
I was stuck on this question haha, You helped me a lot, thanks!
